# WSO2ESB - Sending message to MB with JSON content type

Tags: json, wso2-esb

Using WSO2 ESB, I'm trying to send an AMQP message to the WSO2 message broker. This AMQP message should have JSON content type.

I expose a Proxy service in WSO2 ESB that gets the message, transforms it to JSON and sends it to the message broker. The proxy service configuration looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="json_sample" transports="http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <log level="full"/>
         <header name="To"
                 value="jms:/sample-queue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=sampleConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"/>
         <send/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL>
      <definitions name="JsonSample" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/JsonSample.wsdl" targetNamespace="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/JsonSample.wsdl">
         <message name="JsonSampleRequest">
            <part name="prop1" type="xsd:string"/>
            <part name="prop2" type="xsd:string"/>
         </message>
         <portType name="JsonSample_PortType">
            <operation name="jsonObject">
               <input message="tns:JsonSampleRequest"/>
            </operation>
         </portType>
         <binding name="JsonSample_Binding" type="tns:JsonSample_PortType">
            <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
            <operation name="jsonObject">
               <soap:operation soapAction="jsonObject"/>
               <input>
                  <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:examples:jsonsample" use="encoded"/>
               </input>
            </operation>
         </binding>
         <service name="JsonSample_Service">
            <port binding="tns:JsonSample_Binding" name="JsonSample_Port">
               <soap:address location="http://www.examples.com/JsonSample/"/>
            </port>
         </service>
      </definitions>
   </publishWSDL>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

This proxy service works well, transforming the message to JSON, but do not set AMQP message content type to JSON. The message is considered as text.

When I try to inject an AMQP message in the message broker programmatically, using this code, I really have a message with JSON content type :

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

import org.wso2.andes.client.message.JMSTextMessage;

public class StackOverflowSample {

    private static final String QPID_ICF                 = "org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory";
    private static final String CF_NAME_PREFIX           = "connectionfactory.";
    private static final String CF_NAME                  = "qpidConnectionfactory";
    private static final String CARBON_CLIENT_ID         = "carbon";
    private static final String CARBON_VIRTUAL_HOST_NAME = "carbon";

    private static final String host                     = "localhost";
    private static final int    port                     = 5675;
    private static final String userName                 = "admin";
    private static final String password                 = "admin";
    private static final String queueName                = "sample-queue";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, QPID_ICF);
        properties.put(CF_NAME_PREFIX + CF_NAME, getTCPConnectionURL(userName, password));
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(properties);
        // Lookup connection factory
        QueueConnectionFactory connFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(CF_NAME);

        QueueConnection queueConnection = connFactory.createQueueConnection();
        queueConnection.start();
        QueueSession queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        // Send message
        Queue queue = queueSession.createQueue(queueName);
        // create the message to send
        JMSTextMessage textMessage = (JMSTextMessage) queueSession
                .createTextMessage("{\"prop1\":\"value1\",\"prop2\":\"value2\"}");

        textMessage.setContentType("application/json");

        javax.jms.QueueSender queueSender = queueSession.createSender(queue);
        queueSender.send(textMessage);
        queueSender.close();
        queueSession.close();
        queueConnection.close();
    }

    private static String getTCPConnectionURL(String username, String password) {
        // amqp://{username}:{password}@carbon/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://{hostname}:{port}'
        return new StringBuffer().append("amqp://").append(username).append(":").append(password).append("@")
                .append(CARBON_CLIENT_ID).append("/").append(CARBON_VIRTUAL_HOST_NAME).append("?brokerlist='tcp://")
                .append(host).append(":").append(port).append("'").toString();
    }

}
```

Changing `textMessage.setContentType("application/json");` to `textMessage.setContentType("text/plain");` gives me the same result as using the ESB.

So the question is : how can I configure the ESB to set the AMQP message content type as JSON ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
```

is used to choose message formatter class.

You could have a try with :

```
<property name="ContentType"
          value="application/json"
          scope="axis2"
          type="STRING"/>
```

Comment: Hi Jean-Michel, thanks for answering.
Actually, I already tried to do that, but it does not change the content type (gave me the same result that property set or not).
I also tried to add the ContentType property in "transport" scope, but that only adds the property in the message header, not changes the content.